# How to deal with loop cuts on twisted geometry

Tags: modeling, edges

Say that I have some thing twisted like this thing[image]

And that I want to add a loopcut through what from this view is the inner faces. Following these quads now spills out to the outer faces as well. Repeating the procedure will give more and more spiraly things. How to avoid this, if I still want to have this object as a manifold.

Comment: If this is a mobius ring, as it has only one face I don't see how you can avoid that

Comment: What about putting in n-gons (n > 4) as isolators?

Answer (score 1):

As all mobius strips, there is no 'inner faces'. There is no inner 'edge'. There is but one 'edge', 'The' edge. As well as only one 'face'.

Study the topology yourself, this is the main property of the mobius strip